# WordPress Codex concept about public and registered post types

Tags: wordpress

When I was reading the WordPress Codex about outputting the Post and Pages I saw these two Titles as [Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types)

> Output a list of all **registered** post types

and

> Output a list of all **public** custom post types

now can you please let me know

1. What are **Registered** posts? Is there any un-registered one?
2. What are the **Public** Custom Post Types? is there any Private one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ***unregistered*** post type occurs when we register a post type, add some content to it and then remove the registration. The posts are still there in the database, but they're not viewable/accessible anymore, but once we register the same post type again, they show up.

A ***private*** post type starts by [defining the `public` argument when registering](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments), but it can be fine tuned with the arguments `exclude_from_search`, `publicly_queryable`, `show_ui`, `show_in_nav_menus` and `show_in_menu`.

Many plugins use CPTs for storing their data without it being publicly accessible and hiding its existence from the UI. Some examples are [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/), [BackWPUp](https://wordpress.org/plugins/backwpup/) and [Easy Digital Downloads](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/easy-digital-downloads), among many others.

Answer (score 0):

Themes and plugins can register their own post types in addition to those that come with the WordPress core. Posts and Pages are two of the post types that come out of the box.

If I am coding an event calendar using WordPress, I could for example register a custom post type for events.

When you register a custom post type, 'public' is a predefined flag to show the post type on the administration screens and to make it show up in the site content itself, if it's queried for.